# Adding OR expressions in a loop in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a variable number of **OR** conditions that I want to put together into one Linq query.

How do I do this in a loop?  Basically, the final query is to be:

```
IQueryable<MyObject> Q;
Q = Q.Where(q => (condition1) || (condition2) || ..... || (condition N));
```

Something like:

```
For (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++) {
  Q = Q.Where(q => (existing conditions) || (q.Value == i)); 
}
```

What statement can I use to replace *(existing condition)* in example above without having the final expression (Q) have nested Q's inside them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

You'd need to build an expression tree representing all the conditions you were interested in, combined with `Expression.OrElse`, and then call `Where` a single time at the end.

This may be somewhat tricky if your current source is an anonymous type, but it shouldn't be too bad otherwise. Here's a sample - there may be a simpler way of doing the parameter replacement, but this isn't too bad. (Although `ExpressionVisitor` only works in .NET 4... you'd have to implement something similar yourself if you wanted to use this in .NET 3.5.)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IQueryable<string> strings = (new[] { "Jon", "Tom", "Holly", 
             "Robin", "William" }).AsQueryable();


        Expression<Func<string, bool>> firstPredicate = p => p.Contains("ll");
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> secondPredicate = p => p.Length == 3;
        Expression combined = Expression.OrElse(firstPredicate.Body,
                                                secondPredicate.Body);

        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p");
        ParameterReplacer replacer = new ParameterReplacer(param);
        combined = replacer.Visit(combined);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(combined, param);

        var query = strings.Where(lambda);

        foreach (string x in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    // Helper class to replace all parameters with the specified one
    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression parameter;

        internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
        {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter
            (ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the Replacer doing?

Comment: @Seabiscuit: It's basically making all the parameter expressions in the resulting expression tree refer to the same parameter expression, rather than having separate ones for the top level and each of the "subexpressions".

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But it raises more questions. If I understand you correctly, the Replacer responsiblity is to assign the same parameter expression to both the `firstPredicate` and the `secondPredicate`. What's not clear to me is why, inside the `Where` extension method of the source (here `strings`), the parameters in  `firstPredicate` and `secondPredicate` aren't the same?

Comment: Jon, assuming your example above had three (or more) `OR` statements, how could you use `Expression.OrElse` to create a non-nested sequence of `OR` statements. It would seem to me that the first two would have to be grouped into, say, the left side, and the third expression would be added to the `OR` sequence on the right side, so to speak. But then the first two expressions would be evaluated as a group, and then the third expression would be evaluated, negating the OP's question.

Comment: @Seabiscuit: No, it would evaluate the first expression, then the second, then the third etc - due to short-circuiting. `(a || b || c)` in normal C# is just `((a || b) || c)` after all. It's not like there's a ternary `||` operator.

Comment: Right. So obvious I missed it. And I guess that also works for `AndAlso`, where `((a && b) && c) == (a && (b && c)) == (a && b && c)`, where either all expressions are true, or the entire set is false.

Comment: Thank you. This was very illuminating. The replacer drives me nuts, but it works great.

Answer (score 6):

A less-than-optimized version (pray that the backend will do the necessary lifting and optimization).

```
public static IQueryable<T> Any<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, 
  params Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] preds)
{
  var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

  Expression body = Expression.Constant(false);

  foreach (var pred in preds)
  {
    body = Expression.OrElse(body, Expression.Invoke(pred, par));
  }

  var ff = Expression.Lambda(body, par) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;

  return q.Where(ff);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var q = new[] { "jim", "bob", "Jon", "leppie" }.AsQueryable();

  Expression<Func<string, bool>>[] preds =
  {
    x => x == "Jon",
    x => x == "Skeet",
    x => x == "leppie"
  };

  var result = q.Any(preds).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsThatMatchAny<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<Func<T,bool>> predicates)
    {      
      return source.Where(t => predicates.Any(predicate => predicate(t)));
    }
```

An example of a predicate generator:

```
private static IEnumerable<Func<MyClass, bool>> GetPredicates (int num)
{
   var predicates = new Func<MyClass, bool>[] {m => m.Foo == 3, m => m.Bar =="x", m => DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday};

   return predicates.Take (num);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar idea, but unfortunately this fails with Linq2Sql.