# Parameter Replacement when the parameter is an complex object

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, expressionvisitor

I'm trying to create a dynamic `AndAlso` filter that will be used in a `Where` method to a `LINQ-to-EF` query:

```
query.Where(filterExpression)
```

where `filterExpression` is a compiled lambda

So far I've implemented a loop with some fancy usage to check for cases where there is only one, two, or more queries.

```
Expression selectLeft = null;
Expression selectRight = null;
Expression filterExpression = null;

foreach (QueryColumn columnQuery in querycolumns)
{
    Expression<Func<FileColumnRecords, bool>> 
                columnPredicate = d => d.fcv.Any(f => (f.value != null ? 
                                  f.value.ToLower().Contains(columnQuery.queryTerm.ToLower()) :
                                  false));

    if (selectLeft == null)
    {
        selectLeft = columnPredicate.Body;
        filterExpression = selectLeft;
        continue;
    }
    if (selectRight == null)
    {
        selectRight = columnPredicate.Body;
        filterExpression =
        Expression.AndAlso(selectLeft, selectRight);
        continue;
    }

    filterExpression =
            Expression.AndAlso(filterExpression, columnPredicate.Body);
}
```

Then I set up a `ParameterReplacer` to ensure all iterations of my expression parameter get the same reference:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FileColumnRecords), "p");
ParameterReplacer replacer = new ParameterReplacer(param);
filterExpression = replacer.Visit(filterExpression);
```

which is built from:

```
class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression parameter;

    internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter
        (ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

(`ParameterReplacer` class courtesy of [JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455635/2112866))

When run the `ParameterReplacer` I get the following error:

```
"Property 'System.String value' is not defined for type 'Models.FileColumnRecords'"
```

where `FileColumnRecords` is defined as:

```
public class FileColumnRecords
{       
    public Documents doc;

    public IEnumerable<FileColumnValues> fcv;
}
```

and `FileColumnValues` as:

```
public partial class FileColumnValues
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CNID { get; set; }
    public long fileID { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into difficulties due to there being parameters embedded within your expression tree, I suspect. The replacer should only replace the top-level parameters.

You could pass the top-level expressions into `ParameterReplacer`:

```
class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression target;
    private readonly ISet<ParameterExpression> sources;

    internal ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression target,
                               IEnumerable<LambdaExpression> expressions)
    {
        this.target = target;
        sources = new HashSet<ParameterExpression>(
            expressions.SelectMany(e => e.Parameters));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter
        (ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return sources.Contains(node) ? target : node;
    }
}
```

You'd then need to change the rest of your code to build up the list of expression trees you've been combining. There are definitely more elegant ways of doing it, but I think that should work. That's just off the top of my head though - I haven't tried it.

Having said all this, are you sure you can't just use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Jon! `PredicateBuilder` looks really interesting. You think it would be possible to pass my entire `columnPredicate` to the `PredicateBuilder` or would I have to build an expression tree as you suggest in your answer?

Comment: @Seabiscuit: I don't quite follow what you're doing, but I suspect you could pass in the whole `columnPredicate`.

Comment: It's definitely worth trying out. Let me take this out for a test-drive.

Comment: Holy shirt, Jon! `PredicateBuilder` worked like a charm!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JonSkeet's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25727677/2112866) to this post using an amazing method [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) JonSkeet suggested from the [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library I came up with the following simple solution:

```
public static IQueryable<FileColumnRecords> DynamicColumnQuery
                                (this IQueryable<FileColumnRecords> query, 
                                List<QueryColumn> querycolumns)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<FileColumnRecords>();
    foreach (QueryColumn columnQuery in querycolumns)
    {
        string temp = columnQuery.queryTerm.ToLower();
        predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.fcv.Any(f => (f.value != null ?
                                 f.value.ToLower().Contains(temp) : false));
    }

    return query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

If you know a little bit about writing expression trees then you're immediately going to appreciate how incredibly ***AWESOME*** this is. Plus, note how I have embedded parameters in my predicate.

> I am in no way affiliated with the developers of LINQKit nor Joseph or Ben Albahari 
>   nor O'Reilly publisher. Just an incredibly satisfied developer who thought I should 
>   share the awesomeness of what they built.